# SQL join To Fetch Mutiple Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to find the firstName and Email address from of all teachers and parents in a single query

Here is the structure of the table :

```
// Patients Table
ID        guid             parentID     PatientName
1          234               1258      John
2          xyz               111       Paul


// Patient_teacher table
ID          PatiendGuid      teacherid    
1                122            132
2                xyz            1424
3                245            1545
4                xyz            1222

// Members table 
ID                 guid        email                   fname
22                 123        hello@xyz.com            hello
111                xyz        parentEmail@xyz.com      parentName
1424               343        teacherEmail@xyz.com     teacherName
1222               546        teacher2EMail@xyz.com    teacher2Name
```

And Here is the required Result:

```
//Required Result

fname        Email
parentName   parentEmail@xyz.com
techerName   teacherEmail@xyz.com
teacher2Name teacher2Email@xyz.com
```

The problem is when I tried to search using join I found a single row that contains parentID and TeacherID

Here is what I tried:

```
select Members.email,Members.fname
from Members
    join Patients on Members.guid = Patients.guid
    join Patient_Teacher on Patient_Teacher.patientguid = Patients.guid
where patients.guid = 'xyz'
```

Comment: `// Patients Table` Should that be `// Parents table`

Comment: `// Patients_teacher` ?? Maybe `// Parent_teacher` - `PatiendGuid` ?? Please attention to detail

Comment: ??What teacher table?  where does members table fit in? and more exposition required

Comment: **Please** dont just throw examples together, they are all we have to help try and make sense of your question! this makes very little sense.

Comment: `MYSQL` !== `SQL Server`. They are very differnt beasts. Which one are you actually using? Please dont spam tags, they are designed to attract the correct audience for your question

Comment: It is Patient table not parent where its parent id is actually members id

Comment: I use SQL server but the query is same for both

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the solution I tried can you please check

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Solution :

```
select  Members.id, Members.email, Members.fname
from Patients
join Patient_Teacher on Patient_Teacher.patientguid = Patients.guid
join Members on (Patient_Teacher.teacherid = Members.id 
or Patients.parent = Members.id)

where patients.guid = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the following reasons?

1-    You have a table named `'Patients_teacher'` but in your solution, you're referring to it as  `'Patient_teacher'`.

2-    In `'Patients_teacher'` table, you have a column named `'patiendguid'` but in your solution you're referring to it as  `'patientguid'`.